# Компиляция однотипных классов ant

Tags: java, ant

Всем привет. 
Есть файл build.xml с помощью которого пытаюсь откомпилировать все классы, что есть в пакеты. Исходными данными являются вот эти .java-файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после компиляции появляется уже такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такая цель у ant :

```
<target name="compile" depends="compile_libs">
    <echo message="${msg_info_compile}" />
    <javac
        source="1.8"
        srcdir="${git.src}"
        includeantruntime="false"
        destdir="${git.classes}"
        debug="yes">    
    </javac>
</target>
```

Что это за файлы, как это пофиксить, и почему размер CreateSudokuGUI.java настолько отличается от его .class файла по размеру?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В процесс компиляции java файлов создаются class файлы, которые содержат байт-код. Для каждого класса описанного в java файле создается отдельный class файл. Имя class-файла совпадает с имением класса описанного в коде.

Если класс вложен в другой класс, то его имя формируется из имени внешнего класса, знака **$** и имени внутреннего класса.

Если у класса нет имени (анонимный класс), то в качестве имени берется имя внешнего класса, к нему добавляется знак **$** и число (порядковый номер класса).

**MainForm.java** скорей всего содержит несколько различных компонент у которых добавлены обработчики событий. Каждый обработчик события - это анонимный класс и поэтому компилятор создал несколько файлов: **MainForm$1.class**, **MainForm$2.class** и т.п.

**CreateSudokuGUI.java** вероятно содержит не только класс **CreateSudokuGUI**, но и класс **frame1**, который в свою очередь содержит 2 анонимных класса.